# Famo.us App: Is there a recommended way to call an external API in a standalone famous app?

Tags: ajax, api, post, famo.us

I'm aware that Famous framework does not care about data in the app, and something like AngularJS is the most ideal candidate for the job.

I just want to know how other folks out here are handling data in their apps, specifically POST requests from an external REST API. (since GET calls can be done with the Utility.loadURL() from famo.us itself)

Is AJAX calls the only way to do this right now? (besides Angular/Meteor and the like).
I'm just looking for a clean and simple solution which is easy on beginners like myself.
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a better question for the **[Famo.us Group Mailing List](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/famous)**.  There are a lot of options that are not tied to just Famo.us also.

So, the answer to your question is there is not a recommended way to call an external API in the Famo.us framework as long as it does not manipulate the DOM directly which could have adverse affects on performance. This is addressed in the **[Famo.us Gotchas](http://famo.us/guides/pitfalls)**